# ag-grid: Does the infinite scroll feature support scrolling up rather than down?

Tags: ag-grid

We currently use react-base-table as our solution for an infinitely scrolling table component, but it runs into performance problems with a large number of columns because it does not virtualize horizontally. My understanding is that ag-grid does, so we are looking at it for primarily performance reasons.

Our app defaults to displaying data (log events) from bottom to top. The user is initially placed at the bottom of a potentially large virtual dataset (could be millions of events), and they scroll up to load and view more events (200 at a time).

After reading through ag-grid docs and searching here, I don't see anything about support for an upward direction for infinite scroll. Am I missing anything?

I've tried implementing it with the default row model, but am running into errors (eg "cannot draw while in the middle of drawing rows"). The 'onViewportChanged' event I'm using to trigger a fetch is called several times when rendering, and messes up our data model. Infinite scroll seems like the correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

You will need to set `serverSideInitialRowCount={1000}` so the grid could adjust scroll size. And then in the onGridReady event call `api.ensureIndexVisible(999)`.

The grid will request only the last data block, and will request other blocks as you scroll up.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is one caveat. If the number of rows was finite at the bottom, while scrolling up backend will report unknown amount of rows (even though it's already known) so UI row counter will display incorrect data. Unfortunately, there is no built-in  scrolling direction flag that can be used for calling backend API, so extra frontend logic required.